# UWP - Display Binding of Text with HTML Language on Webview

Tags: c#, webview, binding, uwp

I have a webview in a listbox. The webview is for displaying bindings of text containing html languages, such as `<p>,<img>`,etc.

XAML:

```
<ListBox Name="ListOption" Grid.Row="4" Margin="0,20,10,0" xmlns:m="using:KipinMobile_Win10.TryoutData.Models" SelectionChanged="ListAlternatives_SelectionChanged">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="m:DBOption">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <WebView Source={x:Bind:Option}/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Code:

```
string strA = @"SELECT DISTINCT* FROM DBOption WHERE QID='" + question[0] + "'";
            var alternative = objConn.Prepare(strA);

            ObservableCollection<DBOption> Items = new ObservableCollection<DBOption>();

            int i = 0;
            while (alternative.Step() == SQLiteResult.ROW)
            {
                Items.Add(new DBOption(alternative[0].ToString(), alternative[1].ToString(), alternative[2].ToString(), alternative[3].ToString()));
                if (int.Parse(alternative[2].ToString()) == 1)
                {
                    thisquestioncorrectindex = i;
                }
                i++;
            }

            Binding myBinding = new Binding();
            myBinding.Source = Items;
            ListOption.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, myBinding);
```

I have a problem, that is: can not display text into webview. How to handle it?
Or is there another way to display text containing html language so that `<p>, <img>`,etc is not visible?

Comment: I can't give you a simple answer but WebView is a very expensive control considering each instance spins up it's own underlying IE / Edge HTML rendering engine. You almost certainly don't want these inside a ListBox.

(But if you did, I would suggest written a behaviour that you set the source on, which then calls WebView.NavigateToString - which is the ACTUAL method you need in your case to display "loose" html.

Comment: I can not use the code WebView.NavigateToString and the message appears The name 'webView' does not exist in the current context because webview is in the listbox. How to handle it?

Comment: You need to pass uri to [`WebView.Source`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.source#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_WebView_Source) property. I could not identify the content of `Option` where in your case.

Comment: You can try passing the URL to the WebView's source parameter to verify that the WebView layout is correct.

Comment: Option is data parsing from data on sqlite with DBOption table name. For data on DBOption in the form of text containing html language.